# Position item relative to vertical scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I have a drop down, of a fixed height, that shows multiple items. My drop down looks like so

```
Item 1          >>
Item 2          >>
Item 3          >>
```

When there are many items there will be a scrollbar. Is there a way to position the '>>' symbol relative to that scrollbar? so that theres some padding between it. I've tried relative positioning but it doesnt seem to take into account the scrollbar. The css looks something like the following

```
.item {
 display:inline-block;
 width:75%    
}

.symbol {
 display:inline-block;
 position: relative;
 right:5px;
}

markup:

<div>
   <div class="item">Item 1</div><div class="symbol">&raquo;</div>
   <div class="item">Item 2</div><div class="symbol">&raquo;</div>
<div>
```

So essentially what I want is the '>>' symbol to have some padding on the right when the scrollbar is present or absent. Thanks!

Comment: What you have is a custom drop down. can you share the whole code for creating it or a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about giving your `.symbol` an explicit width like your `.item`, and then using `text-align` to keep it to the right:

```
.symbol {

  display:inline-block;
  width:25%;
  position: relative;
  right:10px;
  text-align:right;

}
```

Like in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6tndK/)...